# Enable Multiline Textbox to sumbit the form on Enter Key in asp.net Webforms

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have a multiline textbox with in a asp webforms panel control with a default button to it. I need to submit the form by hitting the Enter (Return) key than going to the next line in textarea. the code is as below:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlChat" runat="server" CssClass="chat-entry" DefaultButton="btnChat">
     <p>Type Your Message and Press Enter</p>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtChat" runat="server" CssClass="span12" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="4"></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:Button ID="btnChat" runat="server" Text="Send" CssClass="btn" OnClick="btnChat_Click" />
</asp:Panel>
```

I tried with the jquery keypress method

```
  $("#<%= txtChat.ClientID %>").keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
              //  alert('You pressed enter!');
              return false;
            }
        });
```

But the form is not getting submitted by pressing the enter (return) key. Suggestions/solutions are most welcome.

btw: the panel is inside an updatepanel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a hidden button outside the UpdatePanel and call that button's click event to submit the form.

In the markup:

```
...
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" style="display:none" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

In the code:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do whatever you need
}
```

And in the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%= pnlChat.ClientID %>").on("keypress","#<%= txtChat.ClientID %>", function(e){
        if (e.which == 13) {
            var s = $(this).val();
            $(this).val(s + "\n");
            $("#<%= btnSubmit.ClientID %>").trigger('click');
        }
    });
});
```

Although I don't understand why you need to post the whole form when you are using UpdatePanel.

Comment: than you for your solution. It's working fine as expected if I put the `btnSubmit' inside the updatepanel. I have multiple submit buttons in a page with more than one update panel. when I submit the textarea, i wanted to update the contents inside this updatepanel only. if i put the btnsubmit for textarea outside of the updatepanel, the whole page is postbacking.

Comment: I need to use the jquery code inside `function pageLoad(sender, args) {  //code here }` method to get the script worked after partial postback.

Comment: This script is supposed to work outside pageload! Instead of using the event, we are binding the event each time using '.on()'.

Comment: To do a partial postback, you will need the button inside updatepanel. Else it will post the form.

Answer (score 1):

if your Multiline textbox is not working then put your buttons from outside of Update panel. its work perfectly for me. i just put my asp buttons outside of update panel. here is code sample when my multiline textbox text not working.

```
<td style="float: center; padding-left: 155px;">
                                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                                            <ContentTemplate>
                                                <asp:Button ID="btnPre" OnClientClick="Validate();" ValidationGroup="group1" runat="server"
                                                    CssClass="alt_btn" Text="Preview Your Email" OnClick="btnPre_Click" TabIndex="8" />
                                                <asp:Button ID="Continue" OnClientClick="Validate();" ValidationGroup="group1" runat="server"
                                                    CssClass="alt_btn" Text="Continue" OnClick="Continue_Click" TabIndex="8" />
                                            </ContentTemplate>
                                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                    </td>
```

and when i put my button from out side of update panel then multiline textbox text updating perfectly.

```
 <td style="float: center; padding-left: 155px;">
                                                <asp:Button ID="btnPre" OnClientClick="Validate();" ValidationGroup="group1" runat="server"
                                                    CssClass="alt_btn" Text="Preview Your Email" OnClick="btnPre_Click" TabIndex="8" />
                                                <asp:Button ID="Continue" OnClientClick="Validate();" ValidationGroup="group1" runat="server"
                                                    CssClass="alt_btn" Text="Continue" OnClick="Continue_Click" TabIndex="8" />
                                    </td>
```